# Cron job keeps failing in cPanel

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

My cron job keeps failing in cPanel:

```
/bin/sh: /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc: is a directory
```

I have changed the code, previously it was `/usr/local/bin/php`

This is the full code:

`0 0,12 * * * /opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/etc /home4/***/****.org/api/fetch.php`

Does anyone know the reason? The file `fetch.php` works fine otherwise. How do I know where the PHP command is?

Comment: It's possibly an issue inside of your script, but you don't show it.

Comment: The script executes fine when called directly via the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run a PHP file in a cron job, you should run with the PHP interpreter. But your error shows that the cron job is running by the Bash interpreter.

This means you have issue with this part `/opt/cpanel/ea-php73`

You should either revert your interpreter back to `/usr/local/bin/php`
Or you can use the curl command to run the webpage from an external source.
Eg: `0 0,12 * * * curl ****.org/api/fetch.php`

Comment: PHP version was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In the PHP script, you're directly executing an incorrect shell command. Probably a missing `/` prefix in a path.